# Is the tangent bundle of $S^2$, or any manifold in general, locally trivial?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I was recently surprised to learn that $TS^2$ is not trivial. I had a few questions regarding this:

For all $x\in S^2$ does there exist an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $TU$ is trivial? If $(U',\phi$) is a chart of $S^2$ with $x\in U'$ is it true that that $TU'$ is trivial? What if we replace $S^2$ with any manifold?

I also had a more open ended question. How do you visualise $TS^2$? What geometric property of $TS^2$ makes it so that we can't just say it's the same as $S^2\times \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Note this is a very global question. If you remove a single point from $S^2$, the tangent bundle of what's left is trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There always exists an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ of $M$  such that $TU_\alpha$ is homeomorphic to $U_\alpha \times \mathbb{R}^{\text{dim } M}$. The collection of these maps along with the open cover is called a local trivialization, and it can be done for the tangent bundle of any manifold.

I can't say I have a way to visualize the space $TS^2$, but to answer your question about what property makes it non trivial consider this: On $S^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$ there is a non vanishing "section" or vector field, one can pick $X(p)=(p,e_1)$ for any $p\in S^2$ and $e_1$ is the first standard basis vector of $\mathbb{R}^2$. However one cannot find a non vanishing vector field on $S^2$ (this is known as the hairy ball theorem) which tells us that $TS^2$ cannot be trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true for all tangent bundles on all manifolds.  This stems from the fact that tangent bundles are specific examples of vector bundles.  Vector bundles are defined by having locally trivial neighborhoods.